# How to use PAX CDI with Declarative service

Tags: osgi, cdi, karaf, deltaspike

We are using CXF + DOSGI rest services

Interface:

```
@Path("/") 
public interface DefaultApi{ 
 @POST 
    @Path("/public/login") 
    @Consumes({ "application/json" }) 
    @Produces({ "application/json" }) 
    public Response login(@HeaderParam("User-Agent") String userAgent,@QueryParam("username") String username,@QueryParam("password") String password, 
                     @Context UriInfo uriInfo, 
                     @Context ResourceContext recourceContext);
```

Implementation:

```
@Component(immediate = true, configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE, configurationPid = "frontend.rest") 
public class DefaultApiImpl implements DefaultApi {
```

Is it possible to use  Apache Deltaspike for Method level Authorization along with CXF + DOSGI 
https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/security.html
If possible how to do it ?

Is there any other alternative to do method level authorization with CXF + DOSGI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not mix deltaspike and declarative services. Deltaspike security is a cdi extension so you need to use pax cdi to expose your OSGi service.

Another thing is that you need to do the authentication in some way. I recommend to use the CXF [JAASAuthenticationFeature](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cxf.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/interceptor/security/JAASAuthenticationFeature.java;hb=HEAD). It can do basic auth against the configured jaas provider in karaf. The result is a jaas login that you probably can use in deltaspike security to base your authorization on.